# Why is my f1_scores different when i calculate them manually vs output by sklearn.metrics

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

Hi I am relatively new to python and AI and I was trying to explain my f1_scores and I realized that If I calculate my f1 score manually using F1 = 2TP / (2TP + FP + FN) based on my confusion matrix, It is different with what sklearn.metrics returns me.

This is my code

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('diabetes-data.csv')

zero_not_accepted = ['Glucose', 'BloodPressure', 'SkinThickness', 'BMI', 'Insulin']

for column in zero_not_accepted:
    dataset[column] = dataset[column].replace(0, np.NaN)
    mean = int(dataset[column].mean(skipna=True))
    dataset[column] = dataset[column].replace(np.NaN, mean)
    
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:8]
y = dataset.iloc[:, 8]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0, test_size=0.2)

print(X_test)

sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)

classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=11, p=2, metric="euclidean")

import math
math.sqrt(len(y_test))

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

My final confusion matrix is
[[94 13]
[15 32]]

This is where it get confusing, if I calculate the F1 score manually, I get 0.8704. However, in python it returned me 0.6956 using f1_score(y_test, y_pred). Can anyone please explain to me what was the issues?

Additional information:
I tried to print the classification_report(y_test, y_pred)) and this is the output:
*

Classification Report:

```
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.86      0.88      0.87       107
           1       0.71      0.68      0.70        47

    accuracy                           0.82       154
   macro avg       0.79      0.78      0.78       154
weighted avg       0.82      0.82      0.82       154
```

Comment: Could you show the calculus you did precisely with the numbers ? sometimes axis or columns are mixed and not always in the same order when you talk abour confusion matrix. According to scikit doc the first number C(0,0) is TN maybee not what you expected first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scikit numbers order in the confusion matrix are not the same as the order you expect / have in your books/lecture.

For scikit learn order of numbers in the matrix is :

```
TN FN
FP TP

So F1 = 2TP / (2TP + FP + FN) 
F1 = 2*32 / (2*32 + 15 + 13)
F1 = 0.6956
```

is the good answer.

You did the calculs as the matrix numbers were ordered :

```
TP FP
FN TN

F1 = 2*94 / 2*94+13+15
F1 = 0.8703
```

Which is wrong as scikit matrix numbers are not in this order.

Comment: No TP=32 here, this is the trap as scikit doe not use the usual order